# Websphere MQ using XMS.Net

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

I wanted to understand how can I use Web sphere MQ for the following scenario:

1.How I can read the message from the queue without removing that message from the queue.
2. We have a web application so we need the Listener to read the Queue. Is there any tool to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to read message without removing from a queue, it's known as Browsing. You will need to create a browser consumer to read the messages. I have posted snippet here, same code is available in `Tools\dotnet\samples\cs\xms\simple\wmq\SimpleQueueBrowser\SimpleQueueBrowser.cs` also.

```
  // Create connection.
  IConnection connectionWMQ = cf.CreateConnection();
  // Create session
  ISession sessionWMQ = connectionWMQ.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
  // Create destination
  IDestination destination = sessionWMQ.CreateQueue(queueName);
  // Create consumer
  IQueueBrowser queueBrowser = sessionWMQ.CreateBrowser(destination);
  // Create message listener and assign it to consumer
  MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener(OnMessageCallback);
  queueBrowser.MessageListener = messageListener;
  // Start the connection to receive messages.
  connectionWMQ.Start();
```

Callback method

```
    static void OnMessageCallback(IMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            // Display received message
            Console.Write(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in OnMessageCallback: {0}", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any listener tool that i can use for web application?